# JScrollPane doesn't update JScrollBar on JSplitPane

Tags: java, image, drawing, jscrollpane, jscrollbar

I want to create simple app able to edit images. Main view of app contains `JSplitPane` with two `JScrollPane`. Each `JScrollPane` contains `JPanel`. The right `JPanel` has several buttons etc. and the left `JPanel` is my drawing area.

Here is my problem...

When I first created `JPanelDrawingArea` I could set preferred size. If the size is bigger than size of `JScrollPane` the `JScrollBars` show up (in default it is equal). But when I load image to `JPanelDrawingArea` scroll bars don't update. Despite the fact I set new preferred size of `JPanelDrawingArea` (bigger than size of `JScrollPane`) scroll bars don't update unless I manually change the `JSplitPanes` divider position.

Here is my `JSplitPane` custom class:

```
public class DrawingPaneView extends JSplitPane{

private DrawingWorkMode drawingWorkMode;
private ImageWorkerView imageWorker;
JScrollPane workScrollPane;
JScrollPane pictureScrollPane;
private DrawingPaneController controller;

private Dimension minimumSize = new Dimension(100, 200);
private JPanel imagePanel;


public DrawingPaneView() {

    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(ConfigClass.APP_WIDTH,ConfigClass.DRAWING_PANE_HEIGHT));
    controller = new DrawingPaneController(this); 

    //Panel
    drawingWorkMode = new DrawingWorkMode();
    workScrollPane = new JScrollPane(drawingWorkMode);

    //Image
    imageWorker = new ImageWorkerView();
    pictureScrollPane = new JScrollPane(imageWorker);


    workScrollPane.setMinimumSize(minimumSize);
    pictureScrollPane.setMinimumSize(minimumSize);


    //addJPanels
    this.setOrientation(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT);
    this.setRightComponent(workScrollPane);
    this.setLeftComponent(pictureScrollPane);

    //addLeftPanelWithJButtonOnly
    imagePanel = new ImagePanelView();
    pictureScrollPane.setRowHeaderView(imagePanel);

    this.setDividerLocation(ConfigClass.DRAWING_PANE_WIDTH);
    this.setOneTouchExpandable(true);

}

//Change mode
public void changeMode(String mode){
    drawingWorkMode.changeMode(mode);
}      
}
```

And there is my custom `JPanel` which perform drawing:

```
public class ImageWorkerView extends JPanel {

private BufferedImage img;
private ImageWorkerController controller;
private int defaultBounds = 50;
private double scale=1.0;
int imgW;
int imgH;

public ImageWorkerView() {
    //setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    controller = new ImageWorkerController(this);
}


public void setScale(double scale) {
    this.scale = scale;
}

public void setImage(File image) {
    try {
        img = ImageIO.read(image);
        if (img.getType() != BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB) {
            BufferedImage img2 =
                new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            Graphics big = img2.getGraphics();
            big.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
            img = img2;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Image could not be read");
    }
}

private void adjustPreferredSize(Boolean defaultSize){

    if(defaultSize){
        //Calculate the proper size of drawing area
        imgW = ConfigClass.DRAWING_PANE_WIDTH - ImagePanelView.PREFERRED_WIDTH-10;
        imgH = ConfigClass.DRAWING_PANE_HEIGHT-50;
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(imgW,imgH));
        controller.setWindowHeight(imgH);
    }
    else{
        imgW = (int)(img.getWidth() * scale + (defaultBounds*2));
        imgH = (int)(img.getHeight() * scale + (defaultBounds*2));
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(imgW,imgH));
        controller.setWindowHeight(imgH);
    }   
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    if(img!=null){
        if(scale!=1.0){
            AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(scale, scale);
            AffineTransformOp aop =
                new AffineTransformOp(at, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BICUBIC);
            g2.drawImage(img, aop, defaultBounds, defaultBounds);
        }
        else
            g2.drawImage(img, defaultBounds, defaultBounds, null);
        adjustPreferredSize(false);
    }
    else{
        adjustPreferredSize(true);
    }



}
}
```

And how i load image:

```
public class ImageWorkerController {
ImageWorkerView view;
ImageModel model;


public ImageWorkerController(ImageWorkerView workerView) {
    this.view = workerView;
    this.model = ApplicationContext.getObject(ImageModel.class);

    //Load image
    ApplicationContext.getObject(Context.class).addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            if(Context.IMAGE_LOADED.equals(evt.getPropertyName())){
                view.setImage((File) evt.getNewValue());
                view.repaint();
            }
        }
    });

public void setWindowHeight(int h){
    model.setDrawingWindowHeight(h);
}
```

}

As you can see there is `adjustPreferredSize()` method, when it is first called, and it sets `preferredSize` bigger than `JScrollPane`, `JScrollBars` appear. But when it is called again it does nothing.

What is interesting, when I manually change divider's location `JScrollBars` show up, on screen below you have an example:

http://s17.postimage.org/e1nkja3zx/liliebead.jpg

So there is some kind of event, which makes `JScrollPane` to update? I've tried several ways: `updateUI()`, `repaint()`, `revalidate()`. None of them worked.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, you need to `revalidate()` your `ImageWorkerView` (right where you call `repaint()`). This will ask the component and its parent for "re-layout" and that in turn will trigger necessary adjustments for the scroll bars.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer! Your suggestion made me think. What actually I did wrong is call `revalidate()` immediatelly after `repaint()`  so in fact `revalidate()` executes before `paintComponent` method in `ImageWorkerView` (I found this out during debugging). The proper way to do this is:

```
ApplicationContext.getObject(Context.class).addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            if(Context.IMAGE_LOADED.equals(evt.getPropertyName())){
                view.setImage((File) evt.getNewValue());
                //view.repaint();
                view.paintImmediately(new Rectangle(1, 1));
                view.revalidate();
            }
        }
    });
```

So now `paintComponent` sets preferred size and then `revalidate()` adjust scroll bars.